# Taking Last Index of Split

Tags: split

```
public ActionResult MusteriArama(string SeciliMusteri)
{
    if (SeciliMusteri != null)
    {
       foreach (var x in SeciliMusteri.Split(';'))
       {                    

       }
    }
}
```

SeciliMusteri is "Company;50"

I want to take "50" and keep it how can ı do it ?

Comment: Have you tried `SeciliMusteri.split(";")[1]` ?

Comment: What are we looking at? C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is C# (ASP.NET), or an equivalent method is available:

If you don't need to actually split all the parts, you can use [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) instead:

```
SeciliMusteri.Substring(SeciliMusteri.LastIndexOf(';') + 1)
```

---

Alternatively, if iterating through has a purpose, just keep saving the current element as you iterate, the last saved one will be by definition the final one:

```
string lastOne = null;

if (SeciliMusteri != null)
{
    foreach (var x in SeciliMusteri.Split(';'))
    {               
        DoSomethingWith(x);

        lastOne = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
string split[] = SeciliMusteri.Split(';');
string myPart = split[1];
```

or

```
string myPart = split[spit.Length - 1];
```